# regular expression validate textbox at least two words is required

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2012

i have a text box and i need validate it with regular expression at least two words in text box, and not contain spaces in the first character. pls give me a regular expression to validate my textbox

Currently I am using

```
^((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
    controltovalidate="TextBox1" validationexpression="^((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$" 
    errormessage="at least two words"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by `have no white space in first character` ?

Comment: i mean not contain spaces in the first character

Comment: could you provide some examples for valid and invalid strings?

Comment: Please *always* include your language/tool to the tags. Right now, we have no clue what regex flavor you're using.

Comment: asp.net and visualstudio2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they can be separated by any whitespace character (space, tab, etc):

```
^[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)+$
```

Here's the breakdown:

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” `[a-z]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible `+`
- Match the regular expression below `(?:\s[a-z]+)+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible `+`
  - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) `\s`
  - Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” `[a-z]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible `+`
- Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) `$`

...But if they're separated by *only* a space:

```
^[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)+$
```

...or if any non-word character for the separator:

```
^[a-z]+(?:\W[a-z]+)+$
```

This should be used with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. For example (in C#):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^[a-z]+(?:\W[a-z]+)+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: can you tell me where i can find the Regex.IsMatch my validationexpression have not method ismatch

Comment: it doesn't work with "asdasd asdasdas asdasda" can you fix it

Comment: @beginerdeveloper There you go.

Answer (score 1):

Your are probably looking for this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,40}(?: +[a-zA-Z]{2,40})+$
```

Description:

```
^                       # anchor for the start of the string
[a-zA-Z]{2,40}          # ascii letters
(?:                     # open a non-capturing group
    [ ]+[a-zA-Z]{2,40}  # one or more spaces followed by letters
)+                      # repeat the group one or more times
$                       # anchor for the end of the string
```

*Note that word boundaries are useless.*

Comment: it doesn't work i try "abc abc" is valid data but ragular raise my string is not valid data

Comment: @beginerdeveloper: This pattern is designed for asp.net. With which tool have you tested it?

Comment: visual studio 2012 with validationexpression

Comment: @beginerdeveloper: Ok, it will work in your asp.net code. If you want to test it with validationexpression, replace the anchors with `^` and `$`.

Comment: you mean my regular is $((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$

Comment: still doesn't work i fill " " one space validationexpression is pass